# Deserialization Exception in twitter/chill with Play2 and Scala 2.11.1

Tags: scala, serialization, playframework-2.3, kryo

i am using Scala 2.11.1 and Hazelcast 3.5 and twitter-chill for serialization

i have a class User and serializer UserSerializer both on Server(Sbt project) and client side (Play2 project)

i am storing User object in Hazelcast ,
my serializer is working fine on server but the read method of the same serializer gives me exception

here is my serializer

```
 // takes the bytes and converts into User Object  (Deserializer)
   @throws(classOf[IOException])
  override def read(in : ObjectDataInput) : User =  {

     log.info("***********  Deserializer from Client called  ")
      val bytes = ByteArrayConverter.getByteArray(in).toByteArray();
   log.info("Bytes size: "+bytes.length)
   val tryDecode: scala.util.Try[Object] = KryoInjection.invert(bytes)

     tryDecode match {
       case Success(obj) => log.info("  ------ Success case executed ")
                           obj.asInstanceOf[User]
       case Failure(e) => log.info("------ Failure case executed ")
       log.error("deserializer from Client : {}" ,e.printStackTrace())
       null
     }

}
```

the problem is at this line

```
at UserSerializer.read(UserSerializer.scala:44)
```

which is this line from the above method

```
 val tryDecode: scala.util.Try[Object] = KryoInjection.invert(bytes)
```

i dont know whats the problem because same code works fine on Hazelcast server but gives problem on client side

here are the complete stack traces from client side (Play2)

> 17:24:48.822 276580 [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7]
>   UserSerializer INFO - ***********  Deserializer from Client
>   called   17:24:48.839 276597 [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7]
>   ByteArrayConverter$ INFO - ---- object to byte array converter 
>   17:24:48.841 276599 [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7]
>   ByteArrayConverter$ INFO - ---- conversion done now returning the byte
>   array  17:24:48.841 276599 [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7]
>   UserSerializer INFO - Bytes size: 596 17:24:48.917 276675
>   [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] UserSerializer INFO - ------
>
> Failure case executed  com.twitter.bijection.InversionFailure: Failed
>   to invert: [B@1296562     at
>
> com.twitter.bijection.InversionFailure$$anonfun$partialFailure$1.applyOrElse(InversionFailure.scala:43)
>     at
>   com.twitter.bijection.InversionFailure$$anonfun$partialFailure$1.applyOrElse(InversionFailure.scala:42)
>     at
>   scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
>     at scala.util.Failure.recoverWith(Try.scala:203)    at
>   com.twitter.bijection.Inversion$.attempt(Inversion.scala:30)  at
>   com.twitter.chill.KryoInjection$.invert(KryoInjection.scala:29)   at
>   UserSerializer.read(UserSerializer.scala:44)
>     at
>   UserSerializer.read(UserSerializer.scala:22)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:41)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.toObject(SerializationServiceImpl.java:276)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientProxy.toObject(ClientProxy.java:173)
>     at com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:131)
>     at
>   com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapProxy.get(ClientMapProxy.java:200)
>     at
>
> play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(Action.scala:464)
>     at
>   play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(Action.scala:464)
>     at
>   play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(Action.scala:433)
>     at
>   play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(Action.scala:432)
>     at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:556)   at
>   play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:555)    at
>   play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$1.apply(Action.scala:518)    at
>   play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:130)
>     at
>   play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:130)
>     at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)     at
>   play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:129)
>     at
>   play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:128)
>     at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)   at
>   play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:128)  at
>   play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:121)  at
>   play.api.libs.iteratee.DoneIteratee$$anonfun$mapM$2.apply(Iteratee.scala:705)
>     at
>   play.api.libs.iteratee.DoneIteratee$$anonfun$mapM$2.apply(Iteratee.scala:705)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
>     at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41)    at
>   akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
>   Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Unable to find
>   class: User   at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:138)
>     at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:115)
>     at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:610)  at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:721)  at
>   com.twitter.chill.SerDeState.readClassAndObject(SerDeState.java:61)
>     at com.twitter.chill.KryoPool.fromBytes(KryoPool.java:94)   at
>   com.twitter.chill.KryoInjection$$anonfun$invert$1.apply(KryoInjection.scala:30)
>     at
>   com.twitter.chill.KryoInjection$$anonfun$invert$1.apply(KryoInjection.scala:30)
>     at
>   com.twitter.bijection.Inversion$$anonfun$attempt$1.apply(Inversion.scala:30)
>     at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)     ... 36 more Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: User    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)   at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:136)
>     ... 45 more 17:24:48.942 276700
>   [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] UserSerializer ERROR -
>   deserializer from Client : ()